# What clothing did Esther send Mordechai

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, clothing, megillat-esther, mordechai, esther--the-woman

In Megillat Esther (the Book of Esther) [4:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.4.4) it says Esther offered Mordechai clothing. My question is, what clothing did she send?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.4.4?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&p2=Shelom_Esther.4.4.1&lang2=bi It would seem a more refined clothing, more suitable as royal clothing, as the [Steinsaltz says](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.4.2?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&lang=bi&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=en).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rema in [Mechir Yayin](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.4.4?lang=bi&p2=Mechir_Yayin_on_Esther.4.4.2&lang2=bi) writes on the pasuk that it was to lift his spirits:

> שאסתר חשבה לשלוח לו בגדים נאים להסיר השק מעליו שלא יענה נפשו ביותר מדי
>
> That Esther thought to send him nice clothes to remove/replace the sackloth from him so that his soul would not suffer too much.

The Baal Nesivos Mishpot writes in his [Megillas Sesarim](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.4.4?lang=bi&p2=Megillat_Setarim_on_Esther.4.4.1&lang2=bi&w2=About&lang3=en) that it was essentially a coded message:

> מחמת שהי' הכל בהסתר מה הוא לה ואף בדיבור ע"י השליח הי' נזהרין ושלחה לו בגדים אף שהי' לו בגדים לרמז לו כי אצל רחמים
>
> Since everything that was to her was in secret, even speaking was done through a messenger. Thus, she was warning and sent him clothes - even these clothes were to hint to him that mercy was needed...

The Maharal in [Ohr Chodosh](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.4.4?lang=bi&p2=Ohr_Chadash.4.4.6&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) explains that it was a functional action. In other words, she only said that he should take off his sackloth and put on clothes and come to the king's gate to tell her what these things were about. She did not say that he should go to his house and put on other clothes, because Esther did not want to wait so long for the panic to develop. However, Mordechai did not accept, because it was intended for the sake of teshuva.